# Is there a way to consolidate iteration through form controls for different activities

Tags: vb.net, winforms, auto-update, undo

I just started rewriting an application from vba (Access)  to vb.net + SQLServer so not very experienced in .net.

I am creating custom controls (Form + form controls) with a number of extra properties PrevValue, Modified (similar then the one of Textbox), Dirty, DirtyEnabled, SQLColumnName, SQLTableName to enable AutoUpdating and undoing in my forms the form exposes IsDirty, Initialising and Isready properties and an undo method.

Doing so it occurs that I have to write 3 times the same iteration code in different places:

```
For each Ctrl as Control in frm.Controls ' frm being a reference to the form
    if typeOf Ctrl is MyTextBox
        with DirectCast(Ctrl, MyTextBox)
            ' here comes the variable code depending what needs to be done
        end with
    elseif TypeOf Ctrl is MyComboBox
    ' etc.... for MyListBox, MyCheckBox etc....
```

I also have a number of custom controls MyNumBox and MyDateBox that inherit from MyTextBox but with some modified behavior (Formula evaluation, date manipulation, calendar...) how do I avoid doing an extra test on them.

One version of this Iteration is in the SQLProcessClass where the modified controls are added as SQLParameter  and after iteration calling the SQLProcessClass Update or Insert, but ... after successful SQL activity I need to iterate through the controles again to reset the modified flag for each control. Elsewhere I need it to implement a form undo to reset all the controls to their previous values.

It seems to me I have two options
1. repeating that iteration code everywhere I need to iterate through the forms controls. I don't like it as every time I would need to create a new custom control I have to add some lines X times in different modules/classes ... very bad programming
2. Creating one form iteration procedure containing all the different activities that normally belong to another class within that "centralised" procedure, that could be better then (1) but I don't like it that much either.

Is there a better way of doing it using some .net functionality I don't master yet ?

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: `For Each ctrl As MyTextBox In frm.Controls.OfType(Of MyTextBox)`... would loop on just that type and cast `ctrl` as that type;  you'd have to do multiple loops though.

Comment: @plutonix, thks for yr answer but that would not change the logic and the need to copy and paste the same code to different modules for implementation

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through from controls can be tricky since controls are often nested. A more controlled approach would be to add another collection object to your form where you keep references to your added controls.....

e.g

```
Dim My_Widgets as New List(of Your-Control-Class-Name)
```

Then when you create the controls to the form also add them to that list.

```
My_Widgets.Add(Widget_Object)
```

After that it is a simple matter to iterate through that list.

```
For Each Widget as My_Widget_CLass in My_Widgets
    ' do what you need to do to Widget
Next
```

If you need to reference individual controls directly, use a dictionary object instead..

e.g.

```
Dim My_Named_Widgets as new Dictionary(of String, Your-Control-Class-Name)
```

Then add your control references to the dictionary by name

```
My_Named_WIdgets.add("<Whatever_You_USe_To_Identify_It>", Widget_Object)
```

You can then reference the specific control by the ID or name

```
My_Names_Widgets("ID").Property = Whatever '... etc
```

You seem to be indicating you have other controls for other purposes, as such it would be prudent to create similar collections for each type.

Comment: Original idea but that would not change the program logic i.e. I'd have to iterate through each collection individually.... and one would need to change the correct collection for any change in form's structure (dangerous for maintenance). I prefer the recursive iteration for the nested controls